# Method UIToolbar.setItems doesn't work on iOS 6

Tags: iphone, ipad, button, toolbar, ios6

I have the following code that works good on iOS 5.1 to replace buttons on the toolbar:

```
[(UIToolbar*)toolbar setItems:itemsArray];
```

But compiled application doesn't work on iOS 6. I have compiled sources with xXode 4.5 with iOS 6 support but the error is the same:

```
2012-09-27 16:31:13.537 Linux[2633:907] -[UIWebFormAccessory setItems:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1d886ad0
2012-09-27 16:31:13.540 Linux[2633:907] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIWebFormAccessory setItems:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1d886ad0'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x361032a3 0x3441397f 0x36106e07 0x36105531 0x3605cf68 0x775c5 0x33bbda6f 0x360d85df 0x360d8291 0x360d6f01 0x36049ebd 0x36049d49 0x365862eb 0x37428301 0x7538d 0x75328)
libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception
(lldb)
```

How to fix the issue?

Linked issue: [How to replace buttons on a toolbar under UIWebView keyboard on iOS 6?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12622931/how-to-replace-buttons-on-a-toolbar-under-uiwebview-keyboard-on-ios-6)

Thanks a lot for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UIWebFormAccessory is not a UIToolbar on iOS6.  If you want to mess with the form accessory toolbar, check out the "findVirginWebKeyboardToolbar" answer to your related question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12865353/199267

Answer (score 1):

Even if it is a `UIToolbar`, which it might not be any longer, you're obviously trying to call a method (or "send a message") that doesn't exist. The solution is to not do that since the method won't just reappear out of nothing once you try hard enough.

It may be the case that there's another way to continue doing what you're trying to do by finding another fitting method on this undocumented type. However, maybe that will also break someday like this just broke. If they don't document something, yes, it means you can still use it (at least up until you send it for review), but it also means that it might break at any time.

A long term solution is to work out a way to bring up your own interface which you can control yourself. Knowing where you want to integrate, I don't suppose it's very easy. I think I saw another question about that here on Stack Overflow a few days ago saying to detect touches, stop editing and take over the UI yourself (although it doesn't really play well with cursor positioning, copy/paste menus and so on).

Either way, you'll have to devise a new solution that's not so brittle.

Comment: Yeah, on iOS6 it is no longer a UIToolbar.

Answer (score 0):

are you sure the toolbar in this specific case is actually a UIToolbar?  I would guess it's a casting issue.

I do the following in one of my classes, and it definitely works in iOS6

```
NSMutableArray *items = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray: self.topToolbar.items];
[items insertObject:barButtonItem
            atIndex:0];
self.topToolbar.items = items;
```

Comment: It's `UIWebFormAccessory` - a toolbar under keyboard on UIWebView.

Comment: ah missed that in your original post somehow, my bad.  Seems like that is a somewhat undocumented class (there's less than 300 hits when searching for it); not that this helps, but I'm guessing you're not really *supposed* to use it.

Comment: I just want to replace unused buttons on UIWebView toolbar... Please look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12622931/how-to-replace-buttons-on-a-toolbar-under-uiwebview-on-ios-6