# How to replace buttons on a toolbar under UIWebView keyboard on iOS 6?

Tags: iphone, button, uiwebview, toolbar, ios6

How to replace buttons on a toolbar under `UIWebView` keyboard on iOS 6?

The following code works fine on iOS 5.1 but doesn't work on iOS 6:

```
UIWindow *keyboardWindow = nil;
for (UIWindow *testWindow in [[UIApplication sharedApplication] windows]) {
    if (![[testWindow class] isEqual:[UIWindow class]]) {
        keyboardWindow = testWindow;
        break;
    }
}
for (UIView *possibleFormView in [keyboardWindow subviews]) {
    // iOS 5 sticks the UIWebFormView inside a UIPeripheralHostView.
    if ([[possibleFormView description] rangeOfString:@"UIPeripheralHostView"].location != NSNotFound) {
        for (UIView *subviewWhichIsPossibleFormView in [possibleFormView subviews]) {
            if ([[subviewWhichIsPossibleFormView description] rangeOfString:@"UIWebFormAccessory"].location != NSNotFound) {
                UIBarButtonItem *buttonDone =[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Done" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(pressDone)];
                NSArray *itemsArray;
                itemsArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:buttonDone, nil];
                [(UIToolbar*)subviewWhichIsPossibleFormView setItems:itemsArray];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The error on iOS 6:

```
2012-09-27 16:31:13.537 Linux[2633:907] -[UIWebFormAccessory setItems:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1d886ad0
2012-09-27 16:31:13.540 Linux[2633:907] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIWebFormAccessory setItems:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1d886ad0'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x361032a3 0x3441397f 0x36106e07 0x36105531 0x3605cf68 0x775c5 0x33bbda6f 0x360d85df 0x360d8291 0x360d6f01 0x36049ebd 0x36049d49 0x365862eb 0x37428301 0x7538d 0x75328)
libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception
(lldb)
```

Thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: You're trying to set a UIToolbar under the systems keyboard? I salute your futile attempts at messing with UIKit, you're doomed. Did you ever get this working version into the app store ? I would be extremely surprised if you did.

Comment: @Altaveron : Have you find any solution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UIWebFormAccessory is no longer a UIToolbar on iOS6.  It *contains* the UIToolbar you're looking for, though.  Use something like the following to find it on either OS version...

```
+ (UIToolbar *)findVirginWebKeyboardToolbar:(UIView *)parent
{
    if ([parent isKindOfClass:[UIToolbar class]]) {
        // the stock toolbar contains a single item with a UISegmentedControl customView.
        UIToolbar *tb = (UIToolbar *)parent;
        if ([tb.items count] == 1 && [((UIBarButtonItem *)[tb.items objectAtIndex:0]).customView isKindOfClass:[UISegmentedControl class]]) {
            return tb;
        }
    }

    for (UIView *view in parent.subviews) {
        UIToolbar *tb = [self findVirginWebKeyboardToolbar:view];
        if (tb) return tb;
    }

    return nil;
}
```

Comment: Strawtarget, thanks! But the code works only for iPad (on iOS 6.0). Do you have working version for iPhone?

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code to remove unused toolbar:

```
 [subviewWhichIsPossibleFormView removeFromSuperview];
```

And add a new one. Sorry, no code available.